# How can I solve this problem with October CMS on LAMP server?

Tags: php, laravel, lamp, octobercms

I got the following error, when I try load the home page of an October CMS system on LAMP server

```
Declaration of Illuminate\View\Factory::composer($views, $callback) must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory::composer($views, $callback, $priority = NULL)
```

I'm using PHP 7.2, same installation work on WAMP.

Thanks

Comment: _same installation work on WAMP._ or did you just turn error processing off on your wamp stack?

Comment: Thanks. But It is not the reason of the problem.

Comment: There may be some bugs in plugins... Or check your server against [minimum requirements](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation#system-requirements). Anyway, it's strange error.